# CLI library manager for Linux

Tags: file-management, command-line, arch-linux

I use Arch Linux.

I'm looking for something similar to [vifm](https://vifm.info/) and [ncmpcpp](https://github.com/ncmpcpp/ncmpcpp) to manage my library of books and videos. I like the CLIs with vim bindings.

## Must have

- CLI. I don't want a GUI.
- Customizable categories. I want to make my own with things like `id`, `name`, `author`, `tags`, etc.
- Customizable bindings & configs. I make my own bindings and settings a lot.
- Runs an external program (`sxiv`, `mpv`, etc) on videos and images (like vifm)
- Free. I'd rather write my own open-source software than pay.
- Search. Of course I want to be able to search my title, author, tags, etc.

## Nice to have

- Vim bindings.
- Can run custom scripts. I want to make my own scripts for downloading content.
- Central database. I want to be able to interact directly with the database with custom scripts.

Comment: How can a non-GUI/CLI app have dark mode surely that is a function of the terminal/vim/the viewers.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Right I can just set my terminal background.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Calibre eBook](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/) (which has a GUI) and use it exclusively from the [Command Line](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/cli-index.html) &/or the [APIs](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/db_api.html) for integration with VIM, etc. and there is no reason *other than performance & roaming* that you could not have the library located on a network share.

You can certainly add your own [plug-ins](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/creating_plugins.html) to customise behaviour, search, etc.

- Free, yes & Open Source
- Searches - lots
- Custom Tags - yep
- External Programs - yes
- Dark Mode *(to the GUI)* - Via [tweeks](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/customize.html)

If you need to have the library connected via a URL then you are looking for a CMS (Content Management System).

Comment: I don't need the library itself to do anything with the internet. I plan to write my own scripts for that.

Comment: I've downloading Calibre and it's not quite what I'm looking for. Most of the browsing is meant to be done in a GUI. It doesn't seem to have a true CLI like vifm or ncmpcpp,  just some commands. If it has a CLI browser that I haven't noticed, please tell me.